# How do I replace repetitive error handling in Go

Tags: go, error-handling

```
a, err := A()
if err != nil {
  return nil, err
}
b, err := B()
if err != nil {
  return nil, err
}
c, err := C()
if err != nil {
  return nil, err
}
...
```

I have the following code and I would like to avoid typing the conditional statement every single time after every instruction. The only improvement I can think of to improve my code quality is using a function. Could there be anything similar to a `try catch` in go that can make this better ?

Comment: It should be mentioned that `try`/`catch` isn't really a method of error handling. Appropriately handling an error may depend on exactly where it occured and the surrounding context; `try`/`catch` doesn't provide either. It's more aptly a method of exception recovery, which Go has through `panic` and `recover`.

Answer (score -2):

There is no exception management in go. Closure may help here though, here is the gist:

```golang
func() error {
    var err error
    var a TypeA
    var b TypeB
    var c TypeC

    func runner (runnee func() error) {
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        err = runnee()
    }

    runner(func() error {
        a, err := A()
        return err
    })
    runner(func() error {
        b, err := B()
        return err
    })
    runner(func() error {
        c, err := C()
        return err
    })

    return err
}
```

You may also find this blog post from Rob Pike interesting/enlightening https://go.dev/blog/errors-are-values